# Delete empty row in Excel vba after the entire data of that row is copied to another sheeet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete an emptry row in my Sheet.  Originally there's a data in that row and then a macro will cut that data and move to Sheet2 leaving it an empty row.
I want that row to be remove or if there's any row data below, I want them to move up.

[image: screenshot]

```
Private Sub cmdMove_Click()

Dim myLog As Worksheet
    Dim myLogSheet As Range

    Dim i As Long
    i = 1

    i = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Set myLog = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set myLogSheet = myLog.Range("B:B").Find(txtID.Value, , , xlWhole)

    If Not myLogSheet Is Nothing Then
        myLogSheet.Offset(0, 2) = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")

        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")    'Delay to see the punch out time...
        DoEvents

        myLogSheet.EntireRow.Cut Sheet2.Cells(i, "A")

        ' After cutting the entire row, I want the below data to move up to avoid any empty
        'row.. thank you.
        On Error Resume Next

    Else
        txtName.Value = "NO RECORD"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the if part with the following statements, it will work.

```
If Not myLogSheet Is Nothing Then
    Dim foundRow as long
    myLogSheet.Offset(0, 2) = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
    foundRow = myLogSheet.row

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")    'Delay to see the punch out time...
    DoEvents

    myLogSheet.EntireRow.Cut Sheet2.Cells(i, "A")

    ' After cutting the entire row, I want the below data to move up to avoid any empty
    'row.. thank you.
    myLog.Rows(foundRow).select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    On Error Resume Next

Else
    txtName.Value = "NO RECORD"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

At last line, add  this  code

Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).entirerow.Delete